# How do you specify the type of an imported JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I have the following JavaScript file that exports an `AxiosInstance`:

```js
// src/utils/service.js

import axios from 'axios';

export const service = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    timeout: 1000 * 60 * 5,
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

In a different file, I try to import it but get no type inference in VS Code:

```js
import { service } from '@/utils/service.js';
```

I tried using JSDoc notation to specify the type of the import, but it doesn't work with VS Code:

```js
/** @type {import('axios').AxiosInstance} */
import { service } from '@/utils/service.js';
```

How do I specify the type of the imported variable?

Comment: You could create typings for service.js, but is there a reason you don’t write it in TypeScript?

Comment: Since you're working with .js files this looks like a intellisense problem to me rather than an issue with types.

Comment: I'm working on a legacy JavaScript project and can't convert the whole project to TypeScript, I thought the next best thing would be to write it in JSDoc